# How can i solve my data faching problem in react website

Tags: reactjs, console, fetch

I'm trying to fetch my data but there is no data is fetching. also tried to see data in the console but faced same problem. please help me. below is my code screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVwNH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwahi.png)

and this is my code,

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Cards = () => {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setCards(data));
        console.log(cards);
    },[])
    console.log(cards);
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cards;
```

Comment: The error was thrown from a chrome extension, not your application.  What did you get for `console.log(cards)`

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because the fetching happens asynchronously and neither of your `console.log` waits for the data to be in the `cards` state.

You may add to your current code a `useEffect` hook that waits for the `cards` state to change to log that data. Something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
const Cards = () => {
    const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setCards(data));
    },[]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cards.length > 0) {
            console.log(cards);
        }
    },[cards]);

    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    );
};

export default Cards;
```